# ASP.NET Core MVC: Issuing just-in-time response headers from IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter throws under Kestrel, but works under IIS Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis-express, kestrel-http-server

I have an app that issues custom response headers periodically. It only happens when it detects a certain condition at the beginning of request and then automatically issues required custom headers just before the response is served to client.

Since this can happen at any time and with any kind of request, I wrote it using MVC's result filter - `IAsyncAlwaysRunResultFilter`, to be concrete.

This worked nicely under IIS Express, because the filter was always triggered before the response started being served to client, so the custom headers could be written successfully.

But after I switched my project to Kestrel, I started getting exceptions in my filter, saying that *"Headers are read-only, response has already started."*.

Nothing else changed in code, I merely switched to Kestrel for an unrelated reason. Is there a better way for me to achieve what I want, so that it works reliably under both hosts?

My only requirement is that I keep it separate from concrete controllers and actions, because it is a cross-cutting concern, which shouldn't pollute the code of each action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own by dropping the filter and moving the logic into Response.OnStarting callback, which I registered at the beginning of my request pipeline. It now works reliably under both hosts.